# Rails HTTP - POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, post, request

I am sending HTTP POST request:

```
data = { id: 1, name: 'ABC' }

uri = URI.parse('http://localhost:3000/events')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.post(uri, data.to_json)
```

My routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post '/events' => 'receiver#create'
end
```

Whereas create methods looks like:

```
def create
 package = {
  id: ,
  name: 
 }
end
```

How can I get access to data values passing via request? My goal is to assign it to new hash within create method

Comment: Have you tried `params[:id]` and `params[:name]`?

Comment: yes but I get 422 status

Comment: Could you try to change in your *sending* script to: `data = { package: { id: 1, name: 'ABC' } }`, and in your controller try to access it simply with `params[:package]`?

Comment: you should turn off CSRF token in controller and try again. `protect_from_forgery :except => :create`

Comment: I dont know how to solve it still

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set Content-Type header in your request as well:

```
http.post(uri, data.to_json, {"Content-Type" => "application/json", "Accept" => "application/json"})
```

Then you can use `params[:id]` and `params[:data]` in your controller.

```
def create
  @package = {id: params.require(:id), data: params.require(:data)}
  head :no_content
end
```

`head :no_content` will render empty reply (so you can create view later). And `params.require` will ensure that your parameters is provided (otherwise controller will return 400 Bad Request response) – so you won't receive some strange `undefined method ... of nil` errors later in case you missed params in your request.

Comment: Sure. What exactly do you want to do with that data from request?

Comment: create a new hash and assign values from params to specified keys within my new hash

Comment: status 200 and then I can create a new view and display there that hash

Comment: now I get:
Started POST "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-05 11:12:22 +0200
Processing by ReceiverController#create_package as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>1, "name"=>"ABC", "receiver"=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"ABC"}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template receiver/create_package, application/create_package with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.

Comment: Well, that's because you need to first create a new view. Or you could add `head :no_content` to the end of your controller to render empty response.

Comment: I had to use corses in addition but it works fine now